# как в where реализовать case T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, case

Как можно реализовать в условии where оператор выбора case?

Нужно сделать следующее:
хранимая процедура принимает @type int

```
select * from table as t
where case @type when 1 then t.type = 1
                 when 2 then t.type != 1
                 when 3 then t.type = t.type
```

ms sql server 2012

Comment: Имхо, проще всего будет сделать 3 SELECT'а в соответствующих IF'ах.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
declare @t table ([type] int)
declare @type int

insert into @t ([type])
values (0), (1), (2), (3), (4)

set @type = 3

select * from @t as t
where @type = case 
                when @type = 3 then 3
                when t.type = 1 then 1
                when t.type <> 1 then 2
              END
```

Comment: А какое может быть else после проверок type=1 и type<>1 ?

Comment: да, не может. исправил

Comment: Спасибо, Konst. Работает отлично

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from table as t
 where (  (@type=1 and t.type=1)
       or (@type=2 and t.type!=1) )
```